# What is the point of abstract classes, when you could just do an interface

Tags: java, class, interface

I recently began to wonder, why would I ever use an abstract class, when i could just do an interface with the exact same functionality. Consider the following:

```
abstract class abstractClass {

    public int a;

        public void printText(String str) {
        System.out.println(str);
    }
}
```

If I had a subclass extending this, I would be sure to have an integer a and a method named printText.

```
interface Interface{

    public int a = 0;

    public default void printtext(String str) {
        System.out.println(str);
    }
}
```

If I had a class implement this, I would be sure to have an integer a and a method printText.

So, the only difference I see is that with the interface, any class I create would be able to implement as many other interfaces as I would like, but with the extension of the abstract class, I would not be allowed to extend more classes. Why would I ever go for the abstract class? I hope this question isn't too broad, although I can see why some would consider it that.

Comment: That's not a valid interface; you can't have a field on it.

Comment: And interfaces didn't have default method until Java 8.

Comment: Well you proved it to yourself in the question already...

Comment: The `a` in your interface is a constant, not an instance variable. Interfaces cannot declare instance variables.

Comment: Umm, ... fields!

Comment: @chrylis It's a perfectly valid interface, but `a` is implicitly public and static.

Comment: @Michael I should have been more specific, yes; it will compile, but it does not do the same thing at all (note that in addition to public and static, it is also *final*).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few points to consider:

1. Interfaces didn't have default methods until Java 8.
2. That `a` in your interface is implicitly `final`. Interfaces can't define public mutable fields.
3. Interfaces can't define private (or protected, or package) fields.
4. Interfaces can't have protected or package methods; they couldn't have private methods until Java 9.

Abstract classes don't have any of those issues. So when you need to do any of those things (other than #1, now that default methods exist), you reach for an abstract class (perhaps in *addition* to an interface that it implements).

Comment: since Java 9, interfaces can have private methods.

Comment: @AntonBalaniuc - Doh! I'd seen that, too, but managed to forget. Thanks. But still not protected or package, right? (They'd need a new keyword for package, since leaving off `public` wouldn't do it...)